# wx.TxtCtrl loop infinite when formatting input

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to reverse a text typed on a TextCtrl and write it back to the component, through handling the EVT_TEXT event, but I got an infinite loop, after the second character typing.

Bellow, the code:

```
import wx

class NumberTextCtrl(wx.TextCtrl):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(NumberTextCtrl, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnText)

  def OnText(self, event):
    value = self.GetValue()
    value = value[::-1]
    print "value", value
    self.ChangeValue(value)


class Example(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300,100)) 
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    text = NumberTextCtrl(self, id=100)
    sizer.Add(text,1,border=5)    

    self.SetSizer(sizer)    
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title="Example")
    app.MainLoop()
```

What I'm missing, here?

Comment: While it's not my downvote, I imagine it was triggered because there's too much code here to diagnose your issue quickly.  You may also benefit from looking up Masked Controls at http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.masked.textctrl.BaseMaskedTextCtrl-class.html.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, friend. I tried a simple code, where I only append '$', for instance, and I got the same. The formatter was tested by unit test and it is used on web interface, without problem. I notice that, is too easy to fall in that situation with wxPython. I'm researching about the event management, but I don't see what is wrong with this code.

Comment: You will get better help here if you edit your question and post a simple working example of your problem that does not have so much irrelevant code.  Post a complete app that runs, so we can test it.   You just need to add the app=wx.App() call, and show us how you are creating the NumberTextCtrl.

Comment: I edited my question with a simple code. Thanks.

Comment: The code currently in your question works fine for me.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1rrp58ybpdsgg2/Screenshot%202014-02-23%2015.02.43.png

Comment: GreenAsJade, it is wierd. I'm running this same code on Ubuntu with wxpython 2.8.10.1 (gtk2-unicode). I'll try it out on my macbook and see the results... https://www.dropbox.com/s/fv0pjw7ocm2zjxm/Captura_de_tela.png

Comment: Also works fine under Windows7 wxpython 2.9.5 msw classic

Comment: I an confirm that this misbehaves under Ubuntu, same version as you.   Looks like a wxpython ubunutu bug.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that under Ubuntu, calling TextCtrl.ChangeValue() is raising a EVT_TEXT.

You can counter this thusly:

```
import wx

class NumberTextCtrl(wx.TextCtrl):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(NumberTextCtrl, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnText)

  def OnText(self, event):
    self.Unbind(wx.EVT_TEXT)
    value = self.GetValue()
    value = value[::-1]
    print "value", value
    self.ChangeValue(value)
    wx.CallAfter(self.Bind, wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnText)


class Example(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300,100)) 
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    text = NumberTextCtrl(self, id=100)
    sizer.Add(text,1,border=5)    

    self.SetSizer(sizer)    
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title="Example")
    app.MainLoop()
```

But as to why this happens: it looks likes a bug to me.  `ChangeValue()` is certainly not supposed to generate events.

Have you noticed that the problem only occurs if you type *different* characters in?     This is apparently because the call to `ChangeValue()` is not causing an actual change.   So it's as if there is a specific check in the `ChangeValue()` code that consciously decides to sent the event if a real change happens.

Comment: Hello, this happens with any characters,in fact. And, the loop allways starts after the seconding typing. The describes the following, in ChangeValue():                                                                Sets the text value and marks the control as not-modified (which means that IsModified would return false immediately after the call to SetValue).

Note that this function will not generate the wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED event

Comment: There is already a ticket opened: "ChangeValue causes wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED when called from within handler to that event"  http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/12929

Comment: Thanks for finding the ticket!    The loop does not always start after the second typing - if you type 'a' followed by 'a', it stops.  I believe that this is because value = value[:-1] doesn't change value, so no change occurs.   But that is a side matter - at least we know what is going on now, and that it is a bug.

Comment: By the way, does the workaround work for you?   Is there a better one?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Maybe a newe version of wxpython can be useful. I'm using the 2.8.